# How Do I Add A Third & Fourth Slideshow To This Code (and keep it functioning)?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm trying to use w3schools' multiple-slideshow on a friend's page that I'm working on - It works fine with only two slideshows but when you try to add more, things stop working. The third slideshow buttons control the second slideshow & the fourth doesn't show up on the page. I also added the little navigation dots from another w3 slideshow: goo.gl/2bFJk2 , but they don't work either.

I tried altering the code a bit, but my knowledge of JS is pretty limited so I'm sort of just shooting in the dark here. I added more "myslides" to the var slideID, more (1)'s to the var slideIndex and also added more "showslides", trying to use the pattern of the first two (#, #) but no luck so far.

If anyone could help me out with this I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

Here's the url for the w3 slideshow 'try it' page: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_multiple

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides1, .mySlides2, .mySlides3, .mySlides4, .mySlides5 {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a grey background color */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/ajy0x1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2i71vv4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/6p6mhi.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<br>

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides2 fade">
    <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/ajy0x1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2 fade">
    <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2i71vv4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2 fade">
    <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/6p6mhi.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<br>

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides3 fade">
    <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/ajy0x1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides3 fade">
    <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2i71vv4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides3 fade">
    <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/6p6mhi.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<br>

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides4 fade">
    <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/ajy0x1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides4 fade">
    <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2i71vv4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides4 fade">
    <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/6p6mhi.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<br>

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides5 fade">
    <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/ajy0x1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides5 fade">
    <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2i71vv4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides5 fade">
    <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/6p6mhi.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<br>


<script>
var slideIndex = [1,1,1,1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3", "mySlides4", "mySlides5"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(2, 1);
showSlides(3, 1);
showSlides(4, 2);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is "currentSlide()" function?

Comment: My first tip is gonna be to not use w3schools. My second tip is to get into using Vue.js with Bootstrap and Webpack.